# Are separate SSH public keys required for remote terminal and git pushing?

Tags: linux, git, ssh, raspberry-pi, ssh-keys

I'm remotely logging into my Raspberry Pi via SSH. I'm starting to use it for web development testing and would like to push to git repositories from the Raspberry Pi. Do I reuse the public key or do I need to make a new pair of keys? Do I need to use ssh-agent to manage the keys?

The public key used for SSH login is written in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

I already tried making new key pairs with ssh-keygen and adding the new public key as a Bitbucket Deployment key.

Thanks!

Comment: Register the ssh public key of RaspberryPI with your git repo

Comment: I've tried registering both the original public key I use to SSH login (named "authorized_keys") and a new public key (also appended into "authorized_keys").

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037134/ssh-key-keeps-asking-for-password-on-gitlab/26037264?noredirect=1#comment40785641_26037264

Comment: I tried copying "authorized_keys" and renaming it to "id_rsa" and the git push still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pair of key is supposed to represent an identity, i.e. your own machine. Unless you have different machines with different levels of trust (for example, a work machine and a personal machine), you don't need to generate different pair of keys on the same machine for different services.

Concerning key pairs, note that they are *pairs*, i.e. two keys (a public and a private one). `id_rsa` is the usual name of your private key on that machine. `authorized_keys` is the usual name of a list of public keys, for other machines, authorized to log in on that machine. The name of your public key is most certainly `id_rsa.pub`. That's why copying your `authorized_keys` to `id_rsa` elsewhere doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Got it, I finally wrapped my head around it. The machine initiating the SSH connection holds the 'id_rsa' private and public keys. The machine receiving/completing the SSH connection stores the public key in 'authorized_keys'.
I didn't have 'id_rsa' keys on my Raspberry Pi because I've been logging into it remotely from my laptop. So to 'git push' from my Raspberry Pi I'll have to create new 'id_rsa' keys and add the public key to Bitbucket.