# SSH Key Keeps Asking for Password on Gitlab

Tags: macos, git, ssh

I have been debugging the issue for an hour or two now.

I am currently using Gitlab and Mac OS X 10.9.2.

Today, I was trying to `git pull origin master` from our master branch so I can get the latest version to develop on. I have always used these configurations, and don't recall changing anything. This configuration has always worked, and never prompted me for a password. Today, I got this error:

> My-MacBook-Pro:branch_name loop$ git pull origin master
>
> git@domain's password:

Here are my `~/.ssh/`permissions:

```
My-MacBook-Pro:.ssh loop$ ls -l

total 24

-rw-------  1 loop  staff  1766 Oct 31  2013 github_rsa

-rw-r--r--  1 loop  staff   403 Oct 31  2013 github_rsa.pub

-rw-r--r--  1 loop  staff  2408 Sep 15 15:08 known_hosts
```

I have tried various things:

1. restarting `com.openssh.sshd`
2. restarting `org.openbsd.ssh-agent`
3. I made sure that my public key on Gitlab is the same as my `github_rsa.pub`, and it indeed was the same.
4. I have uncommented `sshd_config`'s to `PasswordAuthentication no`
5. Checked `/var/log/authd.log` for errors relating to SSH, but nothing relevant.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename the file github_rsa to id_rsa.

SSH looks for the private key by "name" id_rsa in .ssh folder of your home.

Its not able to find it now because you have renamed it.

PS: Whenever you encounter a problem in SSH try running it with option `-vvv` so that you get a verbose output!

Hope this solves the problem!

Happy Gitting!

Comment: Would the name be the reason if it has always worked with `github_rsa`? How do you run -vvv? Doing `ssh -vvv` or `sshd -vvv` only prompted the help section to pop up (indicating command not found).

Comment: It used to work previously? You were able to have passwordless access?

Comment: I have changed the name of `github_rsa` to `id_rsa`. Upon using `git pull origin master`, I get this prompt: `Enter passphrase for key '/Users/loop/.ssh/id_rsa': `

Comment: While generating the key you would have given a passphrase. That is what it is asking you for no! :)

Comment: That's really interesting. I used `github_rsa` before, and it never prompted me to enter a password to the git URL.. What would suddenly cause it to do so?

Comment: I do not know! Coz for me it never allowed password-less access if I renamed my private key file.


Is it working?


For -vvv: `$ ssh -vvv user.name@domain.com` will give you debug output, just `$ ssh -vvv` will display you help!

Comment: I believe it's because initially you followed these instructions, https://gitlab.com/help/ssh/README, which use `id_rsa`, which is probably different from your `github_rsa`

Answer (score 4):

Fixed this by generating a new public/private key just for Gitlab with no password.

Create a new SSH key:

> ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "name@domain.com"

*Note: For this scenario, when it prompted me to enter a password, I left it blank, since this key is simply for internal use.*

Dump the contents:

> cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Finally, copy the contents to add to Gitlab.